# Ruby on rails: Cucumber w/Capybara goes to ApplicationController on redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, cucumber

I'm trying to set up a RESTful API to a database of redirect links. I have set up a lot of tests in cucumber one of which is when a user does a GET on /links/:id. This is supposed to redirect the user to the link. It works in the browser but I'm having some trouble setting up this test in cucumber.

```
Given /^The link id part of the URL matches an existing entry in the links table$/ do
 FactoryGirl.create(:users)
 FactoryGirl.create(:links, :OWNER_USERID => Users.first.id)
 Users.count.should==1
 Links.count.should==1
end

When /^you use GET on link$/ do
 visit link_path(Links.first.id)
end
```

The link_path specified sends me to this show method:

```
def show
 redir=Links.find_by_id(params[:id])
 redirect_to redir.target, :status=>307
end
```

The problem is just that cucumber fails on the When part complaining that I doesn't have a template for application/index. For some reason it does not redirect me but rather goes to root_path of my own site. Anyone knows how to check if such a redirect actually works?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried testing it in RSpec instead of Cucumber? Try something like this and see if it works:

```
describe "testing links" do
  subject { page } 
  describe "use GET on link" do
    let(:links) { Links.first }
    before { get link_path(Links.first.id) }
    specify { response.should redirect_to("http://example.com") }
  end
end
```

Also make sure your test database if properly configured and populated before doing the tests.

`rake db:migrate` and `rake db:test:prepare`